# Running bash script via Node.js - Illegal option -o pipefail

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, unix, sh

I am trying to exec a bash script via Node.js using `child_process.exec()`. However it is blowing up on the second line of the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eo pipefail; [[ $TRACE ]] && set -x

echo "we are here"
```

The error returned is:

```
/bin/sh: 2: set: Illegal option -o pipefail
```

Why is this happening? When I run the script manually, not from Node it works fine. Here is the Node.js code:

```
var child = child_proc.exec(bashScript, {
    env: _.extend(process.env, {
        'LB_HOST': config.loadBalancers.lb1
    }),
    timeout: 0
});

child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
child.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);
```

Comment: The shell defaults to `/bin/sh` according to https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback - might that be the reason?

Answer (score 4):

By default when you invoke `child_process.exec()` it uses `/bin/sh` which on Ubuntu is actually a symbolic link pointing to `/bin/dash`. Dash is a stripped down version of bash and I guess does not support:

```
set -eo pipefail; [[ $TRACE ]] && set -x
```

Adding the `shell` option to the Node.js `child_proc.exec()` fixes this:

```
shell: '/bin/bash'
```

Comment: Interesting, but why is the `#!/usr/bin/env bash` ignored?