# Linux/Ubuntu set: Illegal option -o pipefail

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, set, ubuntu-16.04

The below mentioned line of code used to work for me all the time on a Ubuntu 16.04 distribution, but suddenly option-name `pipefail` is an illegal option:

```
set -eu -o pipefail
```

returns:

> set: Illegal option -o pipefail

Why does this happen? I run the command on a completely new installed system and as part of a shell script. The code is placed right at the beginning:

myscript.sh:

```
1 #!/bin/bash
2 set -eu -o pipefail
3 ...
```

The script is run as sudo:

```
sudo sh ./myscript.sh
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running bash script via Node.js - Illegal option -o pipefail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36730856/running-bash-script-via-node-js-illegal-option-o-pipefail)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You are running `bin/sh`, on Ubuntu it is a symbolic link pointing to `/bin/dash`, but `pipefail` is a bashism.

Make the script executable:

```
chmod +x myscript.sh
```

and then run the script as follows:

```
sudo ./myscript.sh
```

Comment: This works because the script starts with shebang `#!/bin/bash` which the kernel honors when executing it directly.  `sudo bash myscript.sh` would also work, but like the previous situation it requires the callers of the script to know in which dialect exactly it's written; relying on shebang is great because script is self-documenting and you're free to rewrite it later to different shells (or python etc. or even native executable) 

Comment: `pipefail` is not unique to bash, supported by [multiple shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/654932/17113) but not by `dash`.  But focusing on bash is good, e.g. it lets you [print friendlier errors](https://olivergondza.github.io/2019/10/01/bash-strict-mode.html#is-that-it) relying on other bash features: `trap 's=$? p=("${PIPESTATUS[@]}"); echo "$0: Error ${p[*]} on line $LINENO: $BASH_COMMAND"; exit $s' ERR; set -u -o pipefail`

Answer (score 15):

I had the same error when running script from `zsh` and the script began with *incorrect* shebang.

WRONG, missing `!` after `#`:

```sh
#/bin/bash
rest-of-the-script
```

Correct:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
rest-of-the-script
```